# Split multiple-page PDFs into subparts of fixed size

Tags: pdf, crop

I scanned old documents into multiple pages PDFs (typically, 50 pages). Each of the PDF pages encapsulates several pages of the original document. I would like to preprocess the PDF so that its pages matches those of the original document.

Because the original documents do not all have the same format, this necessarily implies manual stages, such as selecting the pages of the original document (red rectangles in the image below).

Many tools can do that, but given the amount of PDFs, I would like something as convenient as possible, in particular, the red rectangles should have always the same size.

So the workflow would be:

1. Go to page 1 of PDF
2. Choose rectangle size once for all
3. Move rectangle to page 1 of original document, extract
4. Move rectangle to page 2 of original document, extract
5. Go to page 2 of PDF
6. Move rectangle to page 1 of original document, extract
7. ...

This is a typical page of a PDF, the red rectangles correspond the pages of the original documents that I would like to extract.

[image]

**Question** Do you know any tool (Linux or Windows), ideally free, that would relevant for what I am trying to do ?

Note: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49090076/split-long-pdf-page-into-mutiple-pages) is related, but in my case the parts I want to extract are not always at the same position (otherwise it should be done easily with pdfcrop and a little script).

Comment: I tried this in MacOS Preview but no dice - once you press the key combination for crop, the crop rectangle stops operating, and cannot be dragged to another position, much less across to another page. Perhaps you can find a tool which shows the dimensions of the crop box as you drag it, making it easier to recreate the size of box quickly on each page.

Answer (score 0):

I finally decided to write a `Mathematica` piece of code, reproduced here if it can help someone one day:

```
(* import *)
fileName = "mypdf.pdf;
pdf = Import[fileName];

(* desired output size *)
rectangleSize = {1620, 2070}

i = 1;
(* update function: crop and save when clicked *)
update[a_, b_] := Block[{},
  Export[fileName <> IntegerString[i, 10, 3] <> ".pdf", 
   ImageTake[
    pdf[[i]], {a, a + rectangleSize[[2]]}, {b, 
     b + rectangleSize[[1]]}]];
  i += 2;]
(* a function to deal with pages that should not be cropped, if any *)
relaxCropSize = Block[{},
  buffer = rectangleSize;
  rectangleSize = ImageDimensions[pdf[[i]]];]

 (* the "interface" *)
 Manipulate[
 ImageResize[ImageTake[pdf[[i]], {a, a + rectangleSize[[2]]}, {b, 
    b + rectangleSize[[1]]}], 200], {a, 1, 
  ImageDimensions[pdf[[i]]][[2]] - rectangleSize[[2]]}, {b, 1, 
  ImageDimensions[pdf[[i]]][[1]] - rectangleSize[[1]]},
 Row[{Spacer[100], 
   Button["Save and next page", update[a, b], Method -> "Queued", 
    ImageSize -> 100]}],
 Row[{Spacer[100], 
   Button["Relax Crop Size", relaxCropSize, Method -> "Queued", 
    ImageSize -> 100]}]]
```

Slide `a` and `b` to adjust rectangle, click "save and next page" to save the result and go to next page.

[image]